# how to detect that tablerow has been pressed

Tags: android, tablelayout

i know that i can use this for each tablerow but it's very long code

```
setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
    public void onClick(View v)
        {
            //perform action
        }
     });
```

but i have 12 table row i think that this is very long.. maybe with this structure

```
tablelayout {
 if (tablerow.id = 1) {
   // action if i pressed the first row
 } else if (tablerow.id = 2) {
   // action if i pressed the second row
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `setOnItemClickListener` directly on your `ListView`. So, instead of calling `setOnClickListener` in your adapter's `getView` method, just use this:

```
ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);//or whatever the id is
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //then use a switch statement
        switch(position) {
            case 1 : 
                //do something if first row is clicked
                break;
            case 2 : 
                //row 2 clicked
                break;//don't forget these breaks
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: But i dont have ListView, i have TableLayout... I have ScrollView > TableLayout > 12 TableRow

Comment: @user1959076, the same method will work for your `TableLayout`, or any subclass of an `AdapterView`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `View.setTag(Object obj)`:

```
OnClickListener mListener = new OnClickListener() {  
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Integer tag = (Integer)v.getTag();
        switch (tag.intValue()) {
            case ROW1: ...
        }
    }
 });
```

and the time you fill your rows just do (maybe in a loop over all row-ids):

```
TableRow row = tableLayout.findViewById(ROW1);
row.setTag(ROW1);
row.setOnClickListener(mListener);
```

By the way, the Tag can also be set in XML...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a TableLayout, you can add the individual OnClickListener to the elements that are inside of your TableRow (which is inside of your TableLayout).

For example if you have a Button and a TextView inside of a TableRow and you want your button to do something when clicked, then you should add the OnClickListener to the button. If all of the buttons go to the same place, but send different data depending on the position in the TableLayout then you can do something like this:

```
String[] texts; //The different texts your button could say
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
  final Button yourButton = new Button(this);
  yourButton.setText(texts[i]);
  yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, YourClass.class);
    i.putExtra(yourButton.getText());
    startActivity(i);
  }
}
```

If your TableRow only contains one element, you should be using a ListView instead of a TableLayout as Phil suggested.

I hope that kind of gives you an idea on a direction you can go, but it really depends on what you need to do with the item that is being clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

```
  /************ if table row is dynamic then this method else method 2 is perfect************/
//if we want to applay listener on dynamic tablerow then use this
//sure that perfect 
 TablRowe tr = new TableRow(this);
tr.setClickable(true);
tr.setId(100);// if in loop then add 1 counter with 100 like (100+counter) at end count++ it
 tr.setOnClickListener(this);
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
{
        switch (v.getId())
         {
         case 100: 
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "100", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
             break;

         case 101:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "101", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
             break;
}
/************************** for simple like this ************************/
   TableRow row1 = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.row1);
row1.setonClickListener(this);
public void onClick(View v)
{
switch (v.getId())
         {
         case R.id.row1: 
           // do work
             break;
          }        
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on your answer? Perhaps explaining that `this` needs to implement some interface, and also provide valid code.

Comment: @Eric Platon  hope so now you easily under stand it.